# Result from POST with ngx-restangular,

Tags: angular, restangular

I am trying to integrate **ngx-restangular** in an angular 4 application. The basics are in place but I cannot find how to subscribe to use the result of the POST at all. I am migrating the login code to use restangular for now.

The docs have examples showing how to subscribe to a GET response but the calls don't seem to be exactly the same for post. The examples around are from the docs and show a simple POST, nothing done with the response.

I'm pretty sure this is totally trivial but there is no much info around yet (even in SO), experimenting/guessing is not productive. Any idea of how to do it? Is there some reference that I am missing?